# Detect "Ask Every Time" setting on outgoing calls for Dual Sim Phones

Tags: android, phone-call, dual-sim

I am working on an app that successfully intercepts NEW_OUTGOING_CALL broadcast on outgoing calls and handles calls accordingly. Everything works perfectly fine on single SIM devices.

On Dual SIM devices, I am able to detect which SIM is the default calling SIM by reading the ICCID (it changes depending on which SIM is the default calling SIM) and I am also able to handle calls accordingly (either handle it by my app or pass it back to the native dialer).

The problem I am facing is when users choose the "Ask every time" option. When they choose that option, the ICCID is still read as whichever SIM was set as the default SIM last.

I would like to detect that users have chosen this option so I can pop up a dialog thats asks them, which SIM they want to conduct their call over.

I searched through stackoverflow and scoured everything I could find on Dual SIM but I couldn't find an answer to this question. All the logic I added into handling calls on Dual SIM phones has been rendered useless by this part.

Is there something I can read (whether its a broadcast or an intent extra or an android setting) that would tell me that users want to be asked which SIM to use every time they attempt a call?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did u find any solution???

Comment: @YaminiBalakrishnan unfortunately not.